Manga about a girl who jumps to her death and wakes up in a noble's body in another world
The main character's little sister finally dies of illness and she jumps off a building now that her sister is gone, leading to her walking up in the body of a noble girl who has white/blue hair. She ends up coming to the conclusion that the body of the person she is occupying also wants to die, so she goes to a tower with one of those big bells and tries to jump off of it, but she's stopped by one of the male leads.
Also, one of the other male leads is her butler that wanted to kill her previously and knows how to use magic.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

How is the main character involved other than having a sister?

Is this The Duchess Has a Deathwish...?

Despite choosing to die in her previous life, our protagonist is reborn as Selena, the short-lived villainess from a novel. The character Selena was written to be so villainous she spends her final moments isolated in a dungeon. But our reincarnated protagonist has no will to live anyway, so she might as well jump (again) and save Selena from her predetermined miserable fate. But when Selena’s family and a knight prevent her from dying, what can she do…?


A Korean woman throws herself off a building after her little sister dies from illness.



She then wakes up in the world of a novel she'd read as Selena White, a duke's daughter with light blue hair. Having read the novel, she knows Selena is the villainess who is due to be betrayed by her servant and ultimately die of illness in a prison cell alone in a few years time.
Still feeling suicidal, and wishing to spare Selena that miserable death, she decides to try and end her life again by leaping from the top of a bell tower, but the hero of the novel, Sir Lucas, realises what she's up to and stops her just in time.



You can read the full manhwa at Pocket Comics.
